# How to handle the case that a single simple test case will drive the whole implementation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

When I learn "Test Driven Development", I found an interesting case from the book "The Productive Programmer":

> You need to find all factors of a "complete number". A complete number is the sum of all its factors (except the one which equals to the number itself) is equal to the number. So `6` is the minimal complete number, and its factors are `1, 2, 3`.

If I want to TDD, first I want to test an simplest test case:

```
@Test public void completeNumber6() {
    CompleteNumber completeNumber = new CompleteNumber(6)
    assertEquals(completeNumber.findFactors(), new Int[] {1,2,3});
}
```

But ! The problem is this *simplest* case will driven all the implementation of `findFactors()`, which seems too much for me.

The author gives some suggestions, we can split the requirements into several steps:

1. check if number is the factor of another one
2. provide a way to collect some factors into a collection
3. check each smaller number to see if it's the factor of the given number, collect them
4. check if the sum of the collected factor equal to the given number

And we can TDD the first 2 steps first:

```
@Test public void testIsFactor() {}
@Test public void testAddFactor() {}
```

So there will be 2 public (at least non-private) methods after that:

```
boolean isFactor(Int n1, Int n2)
void addFactor(Int factor)
```

The problem is these 2 methods should be **private** after the whole implementation, since they should only used by `findFactors` internally!

But if they are changed to **private**, what shall we do with the exsiting test cases for them?

The author suggests we can change them to **private**, and use Java refection API to get and test them. Sounds possible, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice to do so.

I also asked some friends, and they gave some other options:

1. Keep the methods `isFactor` and `addFactor` non private as is, that's acceptable
2. Extract a class `FactorChecker` and `FactorCollector` for the 2 methods
3. Change them to **private**, and delete the test cases since the functionality of them has been tested in the later test cases (for step 3 & 4)

I'm really puzzled now, which approach is the best practice of TDD?

Comment: Non answer, but it depends. All three can be used with the right class/methods. In this case I think `isFactor` is a valid public method.

Comment: What happens if I execute `new CompleteNumber(1);`? Does it throw an Exception? Did you develop that with TDD? I think you should start there.

Comment: @Manu I don't think `1` is a valid complete number from the definition, and `6` is the smallest I found. For `1` it will returns an empty array, you can think I have written such a test for the invalid case before the `6` one.

Comment: @Manu, thanks for point this out

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the fact that the question states these are complete numbers is somewhat irrelevant. You can calculate the factors of any whole number. So given that I'd start with implementing findFactors(1) and then work my way up.

That makes this a slight variation on the classic [Prime Factors Kata](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.ThePrimeFactorsKata), the only difference being that you add a 1 to list of factors.